# List is getting deleted on page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a list of a class. I am adding the values to the list .

```
lstDoc.Add(new Document
{ 
    No = GridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text,
    Description = GridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text,
    INo = GridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToUpper()
});
```

here I want to delete an item from the list based on the confirmation .If I keep client side confirmation box. on click of OK/Cancel the page will get postback and after that the count of the list will be 0 ; Please let me know How can I retain the values of the list after postback

--
thanks

Comment: What you need is state management to retain values across postbacks and pages. Start by reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Comment: check your aspx page and add this EnableEventValidation="false"  EnableSessionState="true"

Comment: @Esko , you meant to say  that keep the list in viewstate ??? that will be heavy.

Comment: Add some more code

Comment: If you want to keep the object in memory you can use session-variable also or application-scoped variable.

Comment: You can convert that list to json string and store as hidden field value. So, you can get that at server side in each post back. Repeater also an option.